# DateFormat pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" in Gson

Tags: java, timezone, gson

I have two field like below (**pay attention that the first field has milliseconds section**):

```
{
  "updateTime":"2011-11-02T02:50:12.208Z",
  "deliverTime"："1899-12-31T16:00:00Z"
}
```

I want to deserialize the Json string to an object with Gson, so I get a `Gson` instance:

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
gb.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
gson = gb.create();
```

The first field is deserialized to Java date type: *2011-11-02 02:50:12.208* (looks like ignored the time zone section-‘Z’, that's I expected).  However, the second field is deserialized to *1900-01-01 00:00:00* (I live in China, +8 GMT here), it seems that the time zone section-'Z' plays a part in deserialization.

Why the second field uses time zone section? It's not what I expected.

Comment: For me it fails to parse the second date string (`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1899-12-31T16:00:00Z"`). which version of Gson are you using?

Comment: Why do you enclose T and Z in simple quotes '' ? I don't (gson 1.7.1)

Comment: Just to give you morefeedback, my pattern MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss SSSZ gives me dates like this : 02/20/13 18:03:11 089+0100

Comment: To Clemens, sorry I reply so late . I'm using gson 2.2.2.

Comment: To Samuel, the result string was generated in somewhere that I can not control its format. I had tried to delete the quotes, gson would thrown a unknown character exception. What I'm wondering is the difference of convert behavior(one ingore time zone while another would not) if milliseconds field exists.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Quick answer**

First string is correctly parsed using your date format and your local time zone, second one does not respect it, so will be parsed by a default `SimpleDateFormat` object that has not milliseconds ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' is the parsing format) and uses UTC timezone giving you a "shift" in time part.

**Full answer**

To fully respond to your question you need to dive into Gson source code. More in particular you have to look at code of `DefaultDateTypeAdapter` that is used to parse dates. You can find all this code at [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java), but for quick reference I will copy here most relevant parts.

When you call this in the builder:

```
gb.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

you are initializing a DefaultDateTypeAdapter in this way:

```
DefaultDateTypeAdapter(DateFormat enUsFormat, DateFormat localFormat) {
   this.enUsFormat = enUsFormat;
   this.localFormat = localFormat;
   this.iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
   this.iso8601Format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

where:

1. `enUsFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")` and
2. `localFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US)`

since the string you have passed in the builder.

Pay attention that `Locale.US` is not a timezone and that `iso8601Format` is the same as `enUsFormat` without milliseconds but with UTC timezone.

Parsing happens into `deserializeToDate` method:

```
 private Date deserializeToDate(JsonElement json) {
    synchronized (localFormat) {
      try {
        return localFormat.parse(json.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException ignored) {
      }
      try {
        return enUsFormat.parse(json.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException ignored) {
      }
      try {
        return iso8601Format.parse(json.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(json.getAsString(), e);
      }
    }
  }
```

where all of three date formats are used in a waterfall approach.

First Json string: "2011-11-02T02:50:12.208Z". It's parsed immediately by `localFormat` since has milliseconds and gives you the result you expect using your timezone.

Second Json string: "1899-12-31T16:00:00Z". It won't be parsed by `localFormat` since has not milliseconds, so second chance is enUsFormat that is the *same pattern*, except for the locale. So it will fail at the same way.

Last chance to parse: `iso8601Format`, it will, it has no milliseconds, **BUT**, for construction, it as also a UTC time zone, so it will parse date as UTC while the others parsed using your timezone.