# Get Epoch Time From Date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, epoch

I am trying to get the epoch time for a date (2016-03-31T17:58:30.812Z) and I'm having trouble converting. Here is what I have tried:

```
   NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];

    NSDate* tokenCreated = [NSDate new];

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZ"];
    tokenCreated = [df dateFromString:@"2016-03-31T17:58:30.812Z"];

    NSTimeInterval timeTokenCreated = [tokenCreated timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"TIME TOKEN::::%f", timeTokenCreated);
```

What is happening is that `tokenCreated` is being set to nil, and I'm unable to convert. Can someone please point me in the right direction and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateFormat pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" in Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906933/dateformat-pattern-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-in-gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening is that tokenCreated is being set to nil

Because your date format doesn't match your string. For example, your format fails to distinguish between the seconds and the fractional seconds. You would need this:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even see the seconds/fractional seconds. I appreciate the help.